# Prompt variable undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined, prompt

Here i have a short script that will prompt the user to input a message and a number value then repeat that message the given number of times. I continue to receive undefined for the message variable.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>4</title>
</head>

<body>
<p id="change"> Launch this script</p>

<script type="text/javascript">   

    var x;
    var text = "";
    var message = prompt("Enter message here", "Leave a message");
    text == message;
    var number = parseInt(prompt("Enter a Value"));



    for (x=0; x<number; x++)
    {
        text += message.length[x] + "<br>";  
    }
    document.getElementById('change').innerHTML = text;
</script>
<br />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` is equality

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that you have two issues:

1. This line effectively does nothing

   ```
   text == message;
   ```

   Because you used the equality operator (`==`) instead of the assignment operator (`=`), it would be equivalent to writing

   ```
   false;
   ```
2. There's a line in your for-loop that is invalid syntax

   ```
   message.length[x]
   ```

   This should be giving you errors because you are trying to index (`[]`) into the string's `length` property, which is an integer, not an array. That syntax can be used only with objects and arrays. According to your requirements, you should be appending the `message` variable itself.

So with all that in mind, here's my take on fixing up your code (corrected with explanation in comments):

```
<script type="text/javascript">   

    // Don't need x here

    // Get your message, good
    var message = prompt("Enter message here", "Leave a message");

    // Set up an empty string variable to collect your concatenations. If you
    // set it to message right away, an input of 0 will actually produce
    // one line to be output, which is not 0!
    var text = '';

    // This is ok, but add a radix for good practice (it says this is
    // a base-10 value)
    var number = parseInt(prompt("Enter a Value"), 10);

    // You simply want to copy message number times, so just 
    // keep appending it to your text with a separator
    for (var x = 0; x < number; x++) { // Define x here ("var")
        text += message + "<br>";  
    }

    // Set the string
    document.getElementById('change').innerHTML = text;
</script>
```

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3hKw5/2/)</kbd>

Comment: Is change.innerHTML += message + "<br>";  efficient?

Comment: @PixelsTech: No, it really isn't. Pretty slow actually, but assuming that the upper bound for the loop is going to be a relatively small number it shouldn't really matter. I change my code a bit anyway.